# sort parents vertically and child horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

sortable on `part` works fine - `single` are sorted horizontally.

Why `parent` is not sortable - to sort `part` vertically ?

```js
 $('.parent').sortable({
  items: ".part",
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance: "pointer",
  axis: "y",
 });


 $('.part').sortable({
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance: "pointer",
  axis: "x",
 });
```

```css
.parent{
background:silver;
position:fixed;
width:90%;
left:5%;
height:50px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
.part{
background:lightgreen;
margin:5px;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:50% 50%;
}
.single{
background:gold;
cursor:cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='part'>
<div class='single'>lorem1</div>
<div class='single'>ipsum1</div>
</div>
<div class='part'>
<div class='single'>lorem2</div>
<div class='single'>ipsum2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that there is no place to click on `$(".part")` without clicking on `$(".single")`. The target of the sort event is then the part and not the parent.

I would advise either a handle, or some amount of padding.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.parent').sortable({
    items: "> .part",
    containment: "parent",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    axis: "y",
  });

  $('.part').sortable({
    containment: "parent",
    items: "> .single",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    axis: "x",
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: silver;
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.part {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.single {
  background: gold;
  cursor: cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='part'>
    <div class='single'>lorem1</div>
    <div class='single'>ipsum1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='part'>
    <div class='single'>lorem2</div>
    <div class='single'>ipsum2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By adding some padding, 16px worth on the left, I now have a defined space I can grab a Part without grabbing a single, and I can sort it as expected. `items` may not be needed, but it does clarify things when reviewing the code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @qadenza OP is the only one that can mark it as the Answer. The rest of us can Upvote.